# How to send and get data from the server using Ratchet

Tags: php, websocket, autobahn, ratchet

This is the first time I am using sockets and started off with **Ratchet** but I seriously cant fit my head into it. Still tried to join together some parts from the tutorial but facing some problems. Plus I would like to know how to use **autobahn.js** with it. The tutorials are not clear.

**My Problem**

1)   How to send a message to all users except the current user stating "
      ... joined" and the '...' has to be the ip of the user.

I tried the following but it gives me error on the terminal.

```
public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
           // Store the new connection to send messages to later
           $this->clients->attach($conn);
           $this->send('new');
           echo "New connection! ({$conn->remoteAddress})\n";    
}
```

> Call to undefined method MyApp\Chat::send()

2) What to do so that when a message is sent all the parties can view it including the one who is sending it (that's the way how every chat works)?

**JS**

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');

conn.onopen = function(e) {
    //console.log("Connection established!");
    $("#chat_window #messages_list").append("<li class='join_disconnect'>127.0.0.1 Online</li>");
}
conn.onmessage = function(e) {
    //console.log(e.data);
    $("#chat_window #messages_list").append("<li class='thread'>"+e.data+"</li>");
}
conn.onclose = function(e) {
    //console.log("Connection Disconnected!");
    $("#chat_window #messages_list").append("<li class='join_disconnect'>127.0.0.1 Offline</li>");
};



$(document).ready(function(){

        disable_button();


        //EMERGENCY EXIT
        $('#exit').click(function(){
                window.location.replace('http://www.google.com');
        });


        //PREVENT BLANK INPUT
        $('#msg').on('keyup', function(e){

                if($(this).val().length>0){
                    enable_button();
                }
                else{
                    disable_button();
                }

        });

        //SEND MESSAGE
        $('#snd').click(function(){
            var thread = $('#msg').val();
            //console.log(thread);
            //conn.send(thread);
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url: './bin/send-message.php',
                data: {msg: thread},
                success: function(response){
                    //alert(response);
                    if(response!=1){
                        $('#msg').val('');
                        disable_button();
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        //ENABLE BUTTON
        function enable_button() {
            var element = document.getElementById('snd');
            $(element).addClass('active');
            element.style.pointerEvents = '';
        }

        //DISABLE BUTTON
        function disable_button() {
            var element = document.getElementById('snd');
            $(element).removeClass('active');
            element.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
        }


});
```

I know these are a lot of questions but I really want to know how. If there are any step by step easy to learn tutorials those are also welcome.

Comment: your second problem is not clear. please, show your `html` and tell what did you trying to do and what did you get instead.

Comment: and tell us, **how** did you want to use **autobahn.js**? What for?

Comment: According to the docs it said to use autobahn.js for the client side but I couldn't figure out how to use that. And for the second question i was asking that when a message is send by a client, he himself cam see what he sent in the chat area. So how to do that.

Comment: updated my answer with your second question. About `autobahn.js`, yes, it should run at client side. But for what reasons did you want to use it? What is your goal?

Comment: I am totally confused with this library and so many dependencies and really dont know what I am doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to change example from the [tutorial](http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world) at the [Rachet site](http://socketo.me/), than for your first problem solution is:

```
public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    // first, you are sending to all existing users message of 'new'
    foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
        $client->send('new');
    }
    // than,
    // Store the new connection to send messages to later
    $this->clients->attach($conn);

    echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
}
```

Regarding your second question, if I get you right, you should send new messages to all connected clients, like this:

```
public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
    $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
    echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n"
        , $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');

    foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
        // remove this check
        // if ($from !== $client) { 
            // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
            // $client->send($msg);
        // }

        // just send to all
        $client->send($msg);
    }
}
```

---

**Update**: complete solution.

In the `Chat.php`, you need to modify some methods:

```
public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    // first, you are sending to all existing users message of 'new'
    foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
        $client->send('<status>' . $conn->remoteAddress . ' Online</status>'); //here we are sending a status-message
    }
    // than,
    // Store the new connection to send messages to later
    $this->clients->attach($conn);

        echo "New connection! ({$conn->remoteAddress})\n";
}

public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
    $this->clients->detach($conn);

    //send to others clients message about disconnected user
    foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
        $client->send('<status>' . $conn->remoteAddress . ' Offline</status>'); //here we are sending a status-message too
    }

    echo "Connection {$conn->remoteAddress} has disconnected\n";
}
```

in your `js` code, modify next method:

```
conn.onmessage = function(e) {
    //console.log(e.data);
    var match = e.data.match(/^<status>(.*?)<\/status>$/i);
    if (match) {
        if (/\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+ online/i.test(match[1])) {
            messages.append('<li class="join_connect">' + match[1] + "</li>");
        } else if (/\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+ offline/i.test(match[1])) {
            messages.append('<li class="join_disconnect">' + match[1] + "</li>");
        }
    } else {
        messages.append('<li class="thread">' + e.data + "</li>");
    }
};
```

Comment: Yep, I figured that out like two minutes ago seeing your previous answer. But the thing is when a new user joins the joining message which is sent is being sent under onmessage. Is it possible to get it under onopen? So that when the joining occurs its under a different class list? I hope I made myself clear?

Comment: You can see the Js that under onOpen I have something like 127.0.0.1 online, I would like to get the joinning message over there so that everytime a user joins or  leave they get the message under that particular css class.

Comment: I changed a line under onOpen in the php part to $client->send({$conn->remoteAddress}.' online'); but why is it not working?

Comment: @Ayan, because you should change it to `$client->send($conn->remoteAddress . ' online');`. That is, without brackets.

Comment: Okay, that got it working. Pheww.. But what about the css part of the joining client?

Comment: @Ayan, I have to get out of my comp. Hold up, I'll get back in an hour and we'll find a solution =)

Comment: sure..I will hold up..really pretty tough this library.

Comment: @Ayan, are you here? Let's go to the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116918/spirit-ayan)